# Test curried method using PrivateMethodTester

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I'm trying to test a **curried *private* method** (actually *function*) using `PrivateMethodTester` but can't to figure out how to invoke it

Consider following *curried* method:

```
object MyObject {
  ..
  private def curriedAdder(augend: Int)(addend: Int): Int = augend + addend
  ..
 }
```

---

Following gives compilation error

```
assert(9, MyObject.invokePrivate(PrivateMethod[Int]('curriedAdder)(2)(7)))

..
[error] /path/to/MyObject.scala:76:80: org.scalatest.PrivateMethodTester.Invocation[Int] does not take parameters
[error]     assert(9, MyObject.invokePrivate(PrivateMethod[Int]('curriedAdder)(2)(7)))
[error]                                                                                ^
..
```

While this one fails to find the function

```
assert(9, MyObject.invokePrivate(PrivateMethod[Int => Int]('curriedAdder)(2))(7))

..
[info] - my-test-name *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find a private method named: curriedAdder
[info]   at org.scalatest.PrivateMethodTester$Invoker.invokePrivate(PrivateMethodTester.scala:247)
..
```

---

- Is it at all possible to test *curried private methods* using `PrivateMethodTester`?
- If yes, where am I going wrong?

---

Framework versions:

- `"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % Test`
- `scalaVersion := "2.11.11"`
- `sbt.version=1.0.3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following worked for me with ScalaTest 3.0.1:

```
val curriedAdder = PrivateMethod[Int]('curriedAdder)
val actualResult = (MyObject invokePrivate curriedAdder(2, 7))
assert(9 == actualResult)
```

According to [docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/other_goodies#privateMethodTester):

> The private method is invoked dynamically via reflection

When I hear *reflection* I think of [`Object.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html), so calling `MyObject.getClass.getDeclaredMethods.foreach(println)` the method showed up as

```
private int example.HelloSpec$MyObject$.curriedAdder(int,int)
```

and so `curriedAdder(int,int)` was a hint for me on how to call this curried method.